# Updated Vue3 on Rails and vue components stop show up at all without errors :(

Tags: ruby-on-rails, vue.js, vuejs3

I updated from Vue2 to Vue3 and now kind of stuck. I use it inside Rails.
The problem that everything is loading and compiling, not errors at all. I load my web page and see everything instead of Vue files. Don't understand how to fix it at all :(
Any ideas? Maybe I don't see smth or don't know where to looking for it.

If I change smth on the application file it shows some changes or errors. I even deleted everything and add Vue files like in tutorials shows and still nothing to work.

application.js

```
require("@rails/ujs").start()
require("turbolinks").start()
require("@rails/activestorage").start()
require("channels")

import Routes from '../routes/index.js.erb';
import '../css/index.css'

window.Routes = Routes;


import {createApp} from 'vue';
import Customer from '../customer.vue'
import CustomerSearch from '../customer_search.vue'
import CustomerPackages from '../customer_packages.vue'
import BusinessCases from '../business_cases.vue'
import SearchPanel from '../components/business_case/SearchPanel.vue'

import {turbolinksAdapterMixin} from "vue-turbolinks";
import Clipboard from 'v-clipboard'



document.addEventListener('turbolinks:load', () => {
        const app = createApp({
        el: "[data-behavior='vue']",
        mixins: [turbolinksAdapterMixin],
    })
})

app.component('customer', Customer);
app.component('customer-search', CustomerSearch);
app.component('packages', CustomerPackages);
app.component('business-cases', BusinessCases);
app.component('search-panel', SearchPanel);
```

envirement.js

```
const { environment } = require('@rails/webpacker')

const { VueLoaderPlugin } = require('vue-loader')
const vue = require('./loaders/vue')
const erb = require('./loaders/erb')
const pug = require('./loaders/pug')

environment.plugins.prepend('VueLoaderPlugin', new VueLoaderPlugin())
environment.loaders.prepend('vue', vue)
environment.loaders.prepend('erb', erb)
environment.loaders.prepend('pug', pug)

module.exports = environment
```

package.json

```
{
  "name": "backyard",
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "@rails/actioncable": "^6.0.0",
    "@rails/activestorage": "^6.0.0",
    "@rails/ujs": "^6.0.0",
    "@rails/webpacker": "5.2.1",
    "@tailwindcss/aspect-ratio": "^0.2.0",
    "@tailwindcss/forms": "^0.2.1",
    "@tailwindcss/typography": "^0.4.0",
    "@vue/cli": "^5.0.0-alpha.8",
    "axios": "^0.21.0",
    "css-loader": "^5.0.2",
    "dayjs": "^1.10.4",
    "litepie-datepicker": "^1.0.13",
    "node-sass": "4.14",
    "pug": "^3.0.0",
    "pug-plain-loader": "^1.1.0",
    "rails-erb-loader": "^5.5.2",
    "sass": "^1.32.7",
    "sass-loader": "^11.0.1",
    "turbolinks": "^5.2.0",
    "v-clipboard": "^2.2.3",
    "vue": "^3.0.2",
    "vue-clickaway": "^2.2.2",
    "vue-clipboards": "^1.3.0",
    "vue-fuse": "^2.2.1",
    "vue-loader": "^16.2.0",
    "vue-nav-tabs": "^0.5.7",
    "vue-pdf": "^4.2.0",
    "vue-pug": "^4.0.0",
    "vue-turbolinks": "^2.1.0",
    "webpack": "4"
  },
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "devDependencies": {
    "@tailwindcss/postcss7-compat": "^2.0.3",
    "@vue/compiler-sfc": "^3.0.11",
    "@webpack-cli/serve": "^1.3.0",
    "autoprefixer": "9",
    "postcss": "7",
    "tailwindcss": "npm:@tailwindcss/postcss7-compat",
    "vue-cli-plugin-pug": "~2.0.0",
    "webpack-cli": "3.3.12",
    "webpack-dev-server": "^3.11.2"
  },
  "browserslist": [
    "defaults"
  ]
}
```

Comment: [This article](https://mailsnag.com/blog/rails7-vuetify3/) talks about getting rails 7 with turbo drive (turbo links replacement) working together with vue3 and vuetify. Hope that helps you to get it going.

Answer (score 2):

I've had a similar problem and my best guess is the `turbolinksAdapterMixin`. Vue 3 changed and renamed `destroy` hooks to `unmounted` hooks (see [here](https://v3-migration.vuejs.org/breaking-changes/introduction.html#removed-apis)) besides other changes to their Component APIs. I believe, the package [vue-turbolinks](https://github.com/jeffreyguenther/vue-turbolinks) still uses Vue 2 functionalities, such as `$on`, `$off`, and `$once` for [events](https://v3-migration.vuejs.org/breaking-changes/events-api.html#overview).

The way `Turbolinks` works is that the "next HTML body" is fetched via AJAX which in turn replaces the `document.body`.
So, what you need to do – and already did correctly – is to create the Vue 3 App with `createApp` in the event listener for `turbolinks:load` (when the body was successfully replaced).

And then you have to tear down, i.e., unmount, your Vue app as soon as you leave the page (i.e., click a turbolinks link) with `unmount()`.

Hence, you have to replace your code:

```js
document.addEventListener('turbolinks:load', () => {
  const app = createApp({
    el: "[data-behavior='vue']",
    mixins: [turbolinksAdapterMixin],
  })
})
```

with this:

```js
let app;

document.addEventListener('turbolinks:load', () => {
  app = createApp({});
  app.mount("[data-behavior='vue']");
});

// this event listener is executed as soon as
// the new body was fetched successfully but
// before replacing the `document.body`
document.addEventListener('turbolinks:before-render', () => {
  if (app) app.unmount();
});
```